# Regd Harware assisted Virtualization

Tags: virtualization

I am trying to understand hardware assisted virtualization for a project with ARM CortexA8 and using the ARM Trustzone feature. I am new to this topic therefore I started with Wiki entries to understand more.

Wikipedia explains hardware assisted virtialization and adds a line in the definitionas:

> Full virtualization is used to simulate a complete hardware
>   environment, or virtual machine, in which an unmodified guest
>   operating system (**using the same instruction set as the host machine**)
>   executes in complete isolation.

The text in bold is a bit confusing. How is the same instruction set of the processor used to provide two isolated environment? Can someone explain it? ArmTrustzone manual also talk of a "virtual processor core" to provide security. Please throw some light.

thanks

Comment: Just an addition. I thought the CPU in hardware assisted virtualization normally has some special additional instructions. Isn't it? then why same instruction set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "**using the same instruction set as the host machine**" means that the guest OS is not aware of the virtualization layer and behaves as if it is executed on a real machine (with the same instruction set). This is in contrast to the para-virtualization paradigm in which the guest OS is aware of virtualization and calls some specific VMM functions, i.e. hypercalls.

Answer (score 1):

No, CPU has not additional instructions. Virtual machine instruction set is translated by a hypervisor component called VMM (virtual machine manager) to be executed on the physical CPU.

Physical CPU with assisted Virtualization introduced only a new ring 0 mode called VMX that allow the virtual machine to execute some instructions in ring 0.